# Limitar peticiones por segundo | You have exceeded the rate limit per second

Tags: javascript, api, async-await

Estoy intentando realizar peticiones a mi api de https://rapidapi.com/wirefreethought/api/geodb-cities/ pero solamente se puede realizar una por segundo. Dada esta premisa, estoy superando ese límite ya que estoy filtrando los datos con un buscador implementando el evento `keyup`. Intenté hacer una promesa con un `setTimeout` pero igual me genera un error, o sea se ejecuta la promesa esperando esos segundos pero igual sigue apareciendo el problema. Este es mi código:

```
   async function fetchData(query){
       try {
           const response = await fetch(`https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities?limit=10&namePrefix=${query}`,{
               method: 'GET',
               headers: {
                   'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'TOKEN...',
                   'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com'
               }
           
           });
   
           return response.json();
       
   
       } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
   
       }
   }
   
   async function getCities(city){
       let promise = new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, 1500));
           promise.then(async()=>{
               const data = await fetchData(city);
               return data;
           });
   
   }
```

Este es el error:

```
cities.js:4          GET https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities?limit=10&namePrefix=cascas 429
fetchData @ cities.js:4
getCities @ cities.js:24
showCities @ index.js:22
cities.js:25 {message: 'You have exceeded the rate limit per second for your plan, BASIC, by the API provider'}
```

La única solución alternativa que encontré es remover los event por unos segundos y volverlos a agregar. Funciona, pero creo que no es lo correcto.

```
    async function showCities(e){

        search.removeEventListener('keyup',showCities);
        setTimeout(async() => {
           let cities = await getCities(e.target.value); 
                search.addEventListener('keyup',showCities);
        }, 1200);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que con ese código retrasas cada llamada 1.5 segundos, pero no resuelves el problema de tu escenario:

1. El usuario pulsa 3 teclas en menos de un segundo -> Tienes 3 eventos
2. Cada evento genera una espera de 1.5 y hace una petición al servidor.
3. Al pasar 1.5 segundos tienes tres llamadas en menos de un segundo.

La solución que propones al final, aunque no te lo parezca, es la correcta: desactivar el evento durante 1.5 segundos cada vez que se hace una llamada para evitar que se acumulen.

Comment: Entiendo, vale te agradezco!!

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner algo llamado Debounce, esto es una especie de limitador en las veces que se ejecuta una función

```html
function debounce(callback, wait) {
  let timerId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Te dejo Link
https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/curso-debounce-javascript-como-hacer-que-tu-js-espere/